# When creating an XML doctype definition, how do I indicate that in a group of tags, one tag must have a specific attribute?

Tags: xml, doctype, dtd

I am creating an XML DTD, I have a group of tags and ONLY one, must contain an attribute. How do I enforce this in the DTD? Think of a multiple choice question/answer group. See below:

```
<group>
    <question>This is a question</question>
    <question>This is another question</question>
    <question answer="true">This is another question, but this is the correct choice</question>
</group>
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to declare a new kind of element and allow it only once:

```
<!ELEMENT group (question*,questionWithAnswer,question*)>
<!ELEMENT question (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT questionWithAnswer (#PCDATA)>

<!ATTLIST questionWithAnswer type (true|false) #REQUIRED>
```

Answer (score 1):

As formulated, the constraint cannot be expressed in DTDs.

In DTDs, the validation of any element is essentially (modulo ID/IDREF) context-free, so each `question` element is validated in isolation from the others; there is no way to make the validation sensitive to external information like "One preceding sibling has a type attribute".  The best approach to your design issue is that proposed by acdcjunior in his answer to the question:  use the element type names to capture all the information relevant to validation.